# Adding files to initrd makes linux not be able to read it

Tags: linux, initrd, clonezilla

I'm using clonezilla-1.2.12 and need to add the Broadcom firmware to the initrd so it can netboot.

(clonezilla is debian-based and debian no longer includes the firmware blobs as they're non-free. Naturally then clonezilla doesn't either.)

(I can't use the Ubuntu-based clonezilla as Ubuntu has a bug in it where the Broadcom 5708 chipset Just Doesn't Work.)

I have what seems like a good process for doing so:

```
~# mkdir /tmp/cz-newinitrd 
~# cd /tmp/cz-newinitrd
/tmp/cz-newinitrd# xzcat /media/CLONEZILLA/live/initrd.img.orig > initrd
/tmp/cz-newinitrd# (cd /; find lib/firmware/bnx2 | cpio -o -H newc --append -O /tmp/cz-newinitrd/initrd)
/tmp/cz-newinitrd# xz -c initrd > /media/CLONEZILLA/live/initrd.img
```

BUT linux refuses to recognize the redone initrd:

[image: boot failure]

I also tried making a single cpio archive (without using --append) and got the same result.

If I completely skip modifying the archive and just uncompress/recompress I still get the same result.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guilty culprit here was the `xz` step. Looks like the version of `xz` on my desktop was doing something incompatible with the decompressor in the clonezilla kernel.

Switching to gzip makes it works just fine.

---

According to [Steven Shiau](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3392714&group_id=115473&atid=671650), it's necessary to use `--check=crc32` when recompressing the initrd with xz. After doing that, everything works fine!